# weight painting is happening where I'm not doing any painting in blender 2.79

Tags: weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

[image: I cant find the tools tab]I'm doing weight painting, but the paint is spreading out. I just want to paint the bunny's head, but the paint itself is spreading on the body as well. I'm not sure why is it happening and how can I fix this? Could you please help me on this, thanks a lot!!
[image]

Comment: If Yaroslav's answer doesn't answer, maybe switch the Falloff from Projected to Sphere?

Comment: {"my version of blender is 2.79 in which symmetry option is not added"} — not quite so. Your version DOES have symmetry, it's just located in the different menu. I've added to my post an update. Look at the bottom of my posted answer – you will see where you can toggle the symmetry in your version of blender. If that helps - mark my post as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have Symmetry enabled.

How to disable the symmetry:

---

**1. For the new versions of blender (version 3.0 and newer):**

Toggle it in the upper-right corner :

[image: symmetry button]

---

**2. For the old versions of blender (before version 3.0):**

Press [N] button to show the side panel –> On this panel choose the tab [Tool] –> inside this tab choose the section [Symmetry] –> here you can toggle the symmetry :

[image]

Comment: sorry but my version of blender is 2.79 in which symmetry option is not added

Comment: i cant find the tools tab